# Get index of nth element with specific condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let us say we have a `List<int>` with content like `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,0,2,2]` and we want to have the index of the nth number that is not zero.

For example, `GetNthNotZero(3)` should return 6.

It would be easy with a for loop, but I feel there should be a LINQ to accomplish that. Is that possible with a LINQ statement?

Comment: Yes, but pulling in the index complicates things a bit, because most LINQ operations work on the sequence, not the indexes. The notable exception being `Select`, which allows us to do something like `int GetNthNotZero(IEnumerable<int> s, int ordinal) => s.Select((value, index) => (value, index)).Where(t => t.value != 0).ElementAt(ordinal - 1).index;`. Do note that this is much less efficient than a simple loop, what with the constructing of intermediate sequences, and arguably not really much simpler to understand either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an out of the box method, but have you considered writing your own extension method to provide something similar to LINQ's `FindIndex()`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int>{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2 };

        var index = list.FindNthIndex(x => x > 0, 3);
    }
}

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static int FindNthIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Predicate<T> match, int count)
    {
        var index = 0;

        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            if (match.Invoke(item))
                count--;
            if (count == 0)
                return index;
            index++;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I choose this as the answer, although strictly speaking it doesn't provide the "use-just-existing-LINQ" style the question suggests, but I think it is the most straight forward solution and keeps the business logic clean while extending the LINQ features one can use in the code base

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can do that with standard LINQ, you can use:

```
List<int> sequence = new List<int>{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,0,2,2};
int index = sequence.Select((x, ix) => (Item:x, Index:ix))
    .Where(x => x.Item != 0)
    .Skip(2)  // you want the 3rd, so skip 2
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1) // if there is no third matching condition you get -1
    .First(); // result: 6
```

Comment: I think you can't Skip since it may jump over a zero.

Comment: @CjS.: Why not? I don't skip zeros, i skip matching conditions, so != 0. OP wants the 3rd matching condition's index, so i skip the first 2 matching

Comment: Oh - I see - the Where dropped the zeroes - This is clever!

Comment: @CjS.: Here's a net-fiddle, play around with it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ZEg5e

Comment: Works like a charm and is strictly speaking the answer of the question. While I find this LINQ is still good readable and understandable, I tend more to use an extension method when a LINQ exceeds some extend of complexity for a fairly easy task. I thought of a simpler solution. Interesting to see how it could be accomplished with the basic LINQ features.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible, but the Linq approach will make it much more complicated. This is one of those cases where an explicit loop is much better.

Two significant complications arising from using Linq are:

1. Handling an empty sequence or a sequence with no zeros.
2. Synthesizing an index to use.

A Linq solution might look like this (but note that there are probably many different possible approaches using Linq):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ints = new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2 };

        Console.WriteLine(IndexOfNthNotZero(ints, 3));                     // 6
        Console.WriteLine(IndexOfNthNotZero(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10), 3)); // -1
        Console.WriteLine(IndexOfNthNotZero(ints, 100));                   // -1
        Console.WriteLine(IndexOfNthNotZero(Array.Empty<int>(), 0));       // -1
    }

    public static int IndexOfNthNotZero(IEnumerable<int> sequence, int n)
    {
        return sequence
            .Select((v, i) => (value:v, index:i))       // Synthesize the value and index.
            .Where(item => item.value != 0)             // Choose only the non-zero value.
            .Skip(n-1)                                  // Skip to the nth value. 
            .FirstOrDefault((value:0, index:-1)).index; // Handle missing data by supplying a default index of -1.
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation returns `-1` to indicate that a suitable value was not found.

Compare that with a simple loop implementation and I think you'll agree it's better to use a simple loop!

```
public static int IndexOfNthNotZero(IReadOnlyList<int> sequence, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Count; ++i)
        if (sequence[i] != 0 && --n == 0) // If element matches, decrement n and return index if it reaches 0.
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Or alternatively if you prefer (avoiding predecrement):

```
public static int IndexOfNthNotZero(IReadOnlyList<int> sequence, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0, numberOfMatches = 0; i < sequence.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (sequence[i] != 0)           // If condition matches
            if (++numberOfMatches == n) // Increment number of matches, and if it reaches n
                return i;               // then return the current index
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the simple loop as a matter of readability. Ignoring the method's name (which can be made descriptive in either case), it takes more effort to parse the loop than it does to read the LINQ chain line by line. If you showed me only the snippets without further context; I'd be able to tell you what this does quicker with the LINQ snippet. Not that either snippet is unfathomably complex; but I do feel like LINQ's readability is a big plus that the answer somewhat fails to appreciate.

Comment: @Flater This is clearly a matter of opinion. It took me seconds to write that simple loop, and a lot longer to write the Linq because of having to faff around with boundary conditions. Can you look at the Linq and tell immediately what happens if the sequence is empty? Or if it doesn't contain any matching elements? Or if the number of matching elements is less than `n`? You can tell all of those things at a glance in the simple loop, IMO.

Comment: I guess it comes down to LINQ experience, since the questions you pose are (in my eyes) trivially visible. LINQ uses empty collections as much as it can; the only exceptions are when you unwrap the collection into a single element (`First` and `Single`), hence why the `OrDefault` variant exists to handle it gracefully.  For all three questions you ask, one of the chained methods results in an empty collection (respectively `Select`, `Where`, `Skip`). In every case, `FirstOrDefault` receives an empty collection resorts to returning a default value since there is no first item.

Comment: It's also not so much a matter of me liking LINQ syntax, but rather that I find `&& --n == 0` a really unreadable sneaky counter condition. You need to know about short-circuit evaluation and distinguish between `--n` and `n--`, and when making a change, you really have to do the math on when your condition correctly reaches the exit phase. This counter logic is very susceptible to an "off by one" error because of it. Not that it doesn't work, but it is more complex to parse and easier to miss that you've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @flater Like I said, it's a matter of opinion. I definitely think that a simple loop implementation of some kind is better than a Linq solution for this particular problem.

Comment: This is really a matter of taste, and also of consistency. For the code base I am working on, all these kind of tasks are realized with some LINQ, so I tend towards consistency here. If you find LINQ or a loop more readable really depends on your experience. One question, ".FirstOrDefault((value:0, index:-1)).index;" is for me a compiler failure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1503) (VS2019, .NET5 target framework), is it just me?

Comment: @sctty `FirstOrDefault()` with a default value is .NET 6.0 or later only, and you're only using .NET 5.0, so that explains that.